# Unable to connect to cassandra Docker from docker host / externally

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have created cassandra 4.0.6 Docerfile and when testing locally i am unable to access the same on localhost cqlsh. I am getting following error response:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionShutdown('Connection to 127.0.0.1:9042 was closed',)})

Where as following command works fine:

```
docker exec -it cassandra bash -c "cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra"
```

Following is my docker run command:

```
docker run -p 9842:9842 -p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042 -p 127.0.0.1:9160:9160 --network graphnetwork -e CASSANDRA_USERNAME=cassandra -e CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra -v csdata:/opt/cassandra/data -v ./logs:/opt/cassandra/logs --memory=8g --memory-reservation=512m -e ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g --name cassandra  imgcassandra
```

am I missing anything?